# Thick grid-line every 3 rows in a ASP.NET GridView control?

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to have 3 rows in the grid, then a thicker line separating the 3rd from the 4th row, then 3 more rows, then a thicker line separating the 6th from the 7th line, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

ie.

```
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
-------------
Row 4
Row 5
Row 6
-------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work.

Codebehind:

```
private int RowCount { get; set; }

protected void myGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Row.RowType)
    {
        case DataControLRowType.Header:
            {
                RowCount = 0;
            }
            break;
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
            {
                RowCount += 1;
                if (RowCount == 3)
                {
                    e.Row.CssClass = "BorderRow";
                    RowCount = 0;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Css:

```
tr.BorderRow td { border-bottom: 3px solid #000000; }
```

Comment: So there's no way to do this with just CSS or jQuery? I really have to modify all grids in my application?

Comment: Its possible to do it using javascript, but if you're doing anything with header, footer or paging rows it would make a generic javascript solution more difficult.  Are you using any JS libraries (jQuery, prototype, etc.)?

Comment: There is a CSS selector that would easily accomplish this, but its not widely supported  http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: I have jQuery installed, not using it much, I can easily upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Based on chprpipr's answer, here is a more compact solution using modulo and e.Row.RowIndex :

```
if (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if ((e.Row.RowIndex + 1) % 3 == 0)
    {
        e.Row.CssClass = "BorderRow";
    }
}
```

By replacing '% 3' with '% 5' for example, you'll add the BorderRow CSS class every 5 rows instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.MarkRows tr:nth-child(3)").addClass("BorderRow");
});
```

Each `<table class="MarkRows">` or `<asp:GridView CssClass="MarkRows" />` should work, assuming you have the CSS rule I outlined in my .NET solution.